# Effects of power fluctuations on batteries?

Tags: power, batteries, pmsm

When we use an AC motor for the battery, if the motor load fluctuates and the power fluctuation occurs, what will this affect on the battery? As a simple example, if the power changes by 10 + 2 sin (t) versus constant at 10, the average drawing power will be the same. But in both cases, how will the battery consumption or lifespan be affected?

Comment: If power is 10 sin(t), then for one half cycle it will be flowing into a load, and the other half cycle it will be returned by the load. Power in an AC circuit with a resistive load typically has a form something like \$P=P_{peak}\frac{1+ \sin (\omega t)}{2}\$. This form is never negative.

Comment: Oh.. i made a mistake..

Comment: It really depends on the battery chemistry. More often than not the difference is minimal. But you are right, a battery internal impedance is *not* constant nor linear

Answer (score 0):

A battery, over a short period of time, provides a relatively stable voltage. Call it V.

The power (call it P) that is consumed by a load is given by Watt's formula:

$$P = VI$$

where \$I\$ is the current.

If the instantaneous power is given by some formula such as

$$P = 10 + 2\sin (t)$$

Then the current from the battery (assuming the voltage constant) must be

$$I = \frac{10 + 2\sin (t)}{V}$$

Now, in fact, the battery voltage will vary a little under conditions of fluctuating current. A model that is often used for calculating such variations is to assume there is an internal resistance R inside the battery.

The *terminal* voltage \$V_{term}\$ then seen will be *approximately*

$$V_{term} \approx V - \frac{10 + 2\sin (t)}{V} R$$

> how will the battery consumption or lifespan be affected?

For some definition of "small", if the current ripple is "small", the battery consumption and lifespan will not be affected.

It is hard to quantify where the ripple no longer can be considered "small". Certainly if the battery has a rated maximum current, this should not be exceeded. However, one *sign* that battery lifespan or available watt-hours may be compromised is that the internal resistance R, seems to rise.

The reason why R will appear to rise is that R is mostly not "real" resistance, but rather the effect of the chemical reaction in the battery proceeding at a finite rate. Too much ripple, and the rate at which the battery's chemical reaction takes place will not be able to keep up. R will appear to increase.